# EGOTextView issues

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

```
EGOTextView *view = [[EGOTextView alloc]initWithFrame:
      CGRectMake(5.0f,5.0f,310.0f,220.0f)];
      view.delegate = (id<EGOTextViewDelegate>)self;
      view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
      view.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
      //view.clipsToBounds = YES;
      view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      view.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  
      //view.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
      [self.view addSubview:view];
      self.egoTextView = view;
      self.egoTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:25.0f];
      self.egoTextView.attributedString = string;
      [view release];  
      [view becomeFirstResponder];
```

The above code created textview but the first two lines are getting hidden and it is not visible.i need to scroll down to view it.

Also the text set initially not takes the font size mentioned. only when i type text,the font size i have mentioned got it effected.

So how do i need to fix this.
Thanks a lot for your help